# apache2 does not work when I want to open html files

Tags: apache, apache2

I'm a frontend developer and sometimes I need to check my code on mobile for touch events, so I installed apache2 on my computer and copy and pasted the folder of the project in this direction var/www/html/myProject.

The problem is that sometimes it works when I put this as address on my andoird phone 192.168.1.103/myProject and just sometimes it doesn't, no matter what I do , reinstalling it, deleting folders and copy pasting them again..the chrome on my phone just says "This site can't be reached"

BTW I'm on testing Debian 10.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What happens when it doesn't work?

Comment: it says "This site can't be reached" or "the requested URL was not found on this server".

Comment: What happens in the error log of Apache? Use `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log`, you will see live error log. So when you can't see it at random times, go there and try.

Comment: Okay, thanks for helping.I will try that.

Comment: You will then know what the problem is. So I can or someone else can assist you

Comment: Reply back here about the errors, or just post all the errors you have noticed when it is not working. Not the whole error.log

Comment: I think the problem was me being stupid, I used "hostname -I" and saw my local IP was 104 not 103 , I'm testing this today and see if the problem occurs or not and if not I'm gonna delete the post, again thanks for your helps.

Comment: Hey, no problem. Just check it, and may help you if I can.